# Can waste heat in specific environments be collected into photons and converted to electricity?

Tags: optics, electromagnetism, photovoltaics

This question is a [repeat of another post on the physics board](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/627078/289358)

[Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219353/289358) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/572898/289358) show the possibility to combine photons of lower energy to higher energy. Thinking of an application, it could be used to dissipate heat from a laptop. A liquid cooling device could collect heat from a heat sink, then the device makes infrared photons with the heat and sends photons to an "upconversion" device. This device combines infrared into visible light photons and illuminates a conventional solar cell.

One would think of using a thermoelectric generator which still needs to dissipate heat. However, *by imagination* could "upconversion" package *waste heat* collected  and turn it into light? My sentences may appear rudimentary as they are just ideas.

Comment: That sounds like a lot of low efficiency steps cascaded for even lower efficiency to turn low grade waste heat into anything. Efficiency and output matter,

Comment: Agree with @DKNguyen, converting energy into 3 other different forms of energy (heat - photons - higher energy photons - electricity) to try to get something out of it seems like an unlikely way to gather waste heat.

Answer (score -1):

The [second law of thermodynamics](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics) states that [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy)(think heat) of a system only increases. Reversing entropy and [perpetual motion machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion) are specifically ignored by the United States Patent Office because it is impossible for them to work per the second law of thermodynamics. The USPO does not review patents involving perpetual motion and will automatically discharge them without review. So the textbook answer is no. That's why your question was closed by the physics SE group.

There are some [leading edge research papers on LEDs](https://phys.org/news/2012-03-efficiency.html) however that claim to reverse entropy. Based on my own studies it also may be possible to extract energy from [Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion). However these examples are just wishful thinking until proven on a macro scale. It is no small matter to defeat a law of physics, even in a special case.

The applications of such a break through would be much larger than cooling a laptop. It would fundamentally change power production, and the laws of physics.

Comment: So you think the rudimentary idea of mine went against 2nd law of thermo.... alright.

Comment: Potentially if you can identify the cold reservoir in your system (such as the solar panel), it may follow the second law. Efficiency will be limited based on the temperature differential per Carnot. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot%27s_theorem_(thermodynamics)

Comment: Not saying your idea is not possible. Just explaining why everyone will give you a textbook "No".

Comment: @ericnutsch What do you mean by "banned"? If it's impossible, its impossible. Why ban it because of its impossibility? I really don't understand this.

Comment: @Samid, Sorry lazy wording. The USPO does not review patents involving perpetual motion and will automatically discharge them without review. Basically they don't want to waste there time. Might be possible, but again plan on additional hurdles. Haven't read on it in years, but here are some links. https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2104.html   https://www.ipwatchdog.com/2011/10/11/the-patent-law-of-perpetual-motion/id=19828/

Comment: It is possible to upconvert photons via a multi-level pumping system. However, the efficiency of such systems is ridiculously low, meaning a zillion longwave photons per output shortwave photon.

Comment: This doesn't seem to bother the 2nd law, it's just that the 2nd law means there will be losses among the several energy transformations.

Comment: @TigerGuy, Like I said a couple comments above, you just have to identify the cold reservoir and the efficiency is dependent on the differential per Carnot. If everything in the system is at the same temperature however, it is a second law violation.

Comment: Thank all for edits, replies and comments. Well after reflecting on them, I think the core points are that 1) stacking quanta of waste energy transforms themselves into few quanta energy, 2) Making use of thermal energy before it dissipates as waste is a good recycling, 3) electromagnetism is a better stacking method than thermal because thermal energy still needs to go somewhere in random direction. EM waves are directional.

Comment: Maybe while a heat sink and cooling mechanism of either air or liquid are still in place, a layer of thermo conducting material could be sandwiched between plastic or aluminum frames of the laptop and the interior. The outlet of the sandwiched material is connected to a device with two parts. As my question initially stated, the first part makes photons and the second packs longer frequencies photons into shorter frequencies. The photon outlet shines these second photons onto conventional solar panels that are often used on dual-power calculators.